# Gradle, mavenLocal() and --refresh-dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

When declaring the following into my build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

I can re-deploy similar Maven Artifacts (similar = with the exact same version) to Maven local, Gradle will pick up the latest which has been installed, without the need of using `--refresh-dependencies`

If, instead of declaring a `mavenLocal()` repository, I'm declaring a Maven Remote Repository, then I'll have to include `--refresh-dependencies` in order to be 100% sure I'm getting the latest of a published version. No problem here, this is expected ...

However, I don't understand why the same is not true for a `mavenLocal()` repository. I couldn't find any explanation in the documentation: [Declaring a changing version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_changing_version).

Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is disabled for local repositories.

The paragraph [The case for mavenLocal()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local) from the *Declaring repositories* enumerates the various downsides of using `mavenLocal()` and explains the behavior you observe:

> To mitigate the fact that metadata and/or artifacts can be changed, Gradle does not perform [any caching](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sec:dependency_cache) for [local repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:local-repos)